# WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://") returns nil with JRuby

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby, win32ole, jruby-win32ole

I am trying to check if a process exists in JRuby on a Windows 7 machine.
I'm trying:

```
require 'jwin32ole'
wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
processes = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process")
```

However, `WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")` is returning nil.

When I started up Excel, I was able to successfully call `WIN32OLE.connect("Excel.Application")`, so WIN32OLE.connect can work.

Any suggestions on how to get this working, or another way to check if a process exists?

Answer (score 0):

I found what looks like to be the problem.

In jwin32ole, this is the code for connect:

```
def self.connect app
  dispatcher=Java::com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.connectToActiveInstance(app)
  if dispatcher.class.to_s != "NilClass"
    AppDispatcher.new dispatcher
  else
    return nil
```

And looking at [the API documentation for jacob.activeXComponent.connectToActiveInstance](http://pub.open-conflict.de/gui/java%20WIP/Sensors/lib/api/com/jacob/activeX/ActiveXComponent.html#connectToActiveInstance(java.lang.String)):

*This will fail for any prog id with a ":" in it*

Which, of course, will result in a failure while trying to connect to "winmgmts:". Why it doesn't accept colons in not explained.

Another connection method in jacob.activeXComponent would have to be directly used that doesn't have a problem with colons in the prog id.